# Syncing between local sql and server database

Tags: android

Hope you are doing well.
I'm developing an android app, and i need to make synchronization between the local SQL and the database on the server.
I'm using PHP on the server side(JSON for retrieving date).
My problem is when i launch the app for the first time , is dowloads the data located on the server, then when i launch it for the second time , the data is dowloaded again, sometimes it happens and sometimes NOT! 
And when adding new data , it is downloaded , but the problem still happens, the data is duplicated.
When i try the app on my mobile, the data is downloaded once, but when adding new data, it isn't downloaded!
Here is my code.

```
protected Void doInBackground(Void... uri) {
        myDatabaseHandler.openToRead();
        Cursor cursor = myDatabaseHandler.queueBranchId();
        try {
            HttpParams params = new BasicHttpParams();
            HttpConnectionParams.setSoTimeout(params, 0);
            HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(params);

            //prepare the HTTP GET call 
            HttpGet httpget = new HttpGet("http://restaurants.bugs3.com/branches.php");
            //get the response entity
            HttpEntity entity = httpClient.execute(httpget).getEntity();

            if (entity != null) {
                //get the response content as a string
                String response = EntityUtils.toString(entity);
                //consume the entity
                entity.consumeContent();

                // When HttpClient instance is no longer needed, shut down the connection manager to ensure immediate deallocation of all system resources
                httpClient.getConnectionManager().shutdown();

                //return the JSON response
                JSONObject object = new JSONObject(response.trim());
                JSONArray jsonArray = object.getJSONArray("branches");
                if(jsonArray != null) {
                   for(int i = 0 ; i < jsonArray.length() ; i++) {
                            JSONObject object1 = (JSONObject) jsonArray.get(i);
                            int server_branch_id = object1.getInt("server_branch_id");
                            String branch_name = object1.getString("branch_name");
                            double branch_lat = object1.getDouble("branch_lat");
                            double branch_lon = object1.getDouble("branch_lon");
                            double distance = object1.getDouble("distance");
                            String restaurant_name = object1.getString("restaurant_name");
                            boolean exist = false;
if (cursor.moveToFirst())
                            {
                                do
                                {
                                    try
                                    {
                                        if (server_branch_id == cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_LOCAL_BRANCH_ID)))
                                        {
                                            exist = true;
                                        }
                                    }
                                    catch(Exception e)
                                    {   
                                    }
                                }while(cursor.moveToNext());
                                cursor.close();
                            }
                            myDatabaseHandler.close();

                            if (!exist)
                            {
                                myDatabaseHandler.openToWrite();
                                myDatabaseHandler.insertBranchWithID(server_branch_id, branch_name, restaurant_name, branch_lat, branch_lon, distance);
                                myDatabaseHandler.close();
                            }

                   }}catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There could be some workarounds for this. I can suggest two different ways (Assuming you have a specific id for whatever item you download):

1. Keep track of last id at local sql, on app start, ask server if there is newer id and if there is download them. By this way you can avoid replication.
2. Use primary key constraint on table and for insertion use insertWithOnConflict(..., CONFLICT_IGNORE). This method will not duplicate any same ids and insert if there is something different.

Hope this helps

Comment: Thanks for your interest, Here i'm comparing every server_id wih local_id, server_id is auto_increment.
So i don't know why the data is duplicated!
I will try insertWithOnConflict , but i want to know what is the problem on my code, if you observed anything wrong , please tell me.